# SDL 2 Cannot Open Controller but Joystick Recognized

Tags: c++, macos, input, sdl, sdl-2

I am writing a C++ program using SDL 2 for the platform layer and opengl for graphics and rendering. I have a full working prototype with keyboard and mouse input. Now I am now trying to use SDL's game controller API to connect a gamepad (to replace or supplement keyboard controls). Unfortunately the controller does not seem to be recognized despite the fact that it works perfectly with other software. It's a Sony Dualshock 4 (for the Playstation 4 system). My system is Mac OS 10.9.5, and I am using SDL 2.0.5 with the official community controller database for SDL 2.0.5, which contains ps4 controller mappings:

```
030000004c050000c405000000000000,PS4 Controller,a:b1,b:b2,back:b8,dpdown:h0.4,dpleft:h0.8,dpright:h0.2,dpup:h0.1,guide:b12,leftshoulder:b4,leftstick:b10,lefttrigger:a3,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightshoulder:b5,rightstick:b11,righttrigger:a4,rightx:a2,righty:a5,start:b9,x:b0,y:b3,platform:Mac OS X,
4c05000000000000c405000000000000,PS4 Controller,a:b1,b:b2,back:b8,dpdown:h0.4,dpleft:h0.8,dpright:h0.2,dpup:h0.1,guide:b12,leftshoulder:b4,leftstick:b10,lefttrigger:a3,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightshoulder:b5,rightstick:b11,righttrigger:a4,rightx:a2,righty:a5,start:b9,x:b0,y:b3,platform:Mac OS X
```

I also added a new mapping using one of the official tools. That also loads successfully according to the relevant function call.

The following is my code, and it's about as close to a minimal example as I can get:

```
// in main
    // window and graphics context initialization here
    // initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER | SDL_INIT_HAPTIC) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "SDL could not initialize");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // load controller mappings, I tested this and 35 mappings load successfully, which is expected
    SDL_GameControllerAddMappingsFromFile("./mapping/gamecontrollerdb_205.txt");

    // the controller handle
    SDL_GameController* controller = nullptr;
    // max_joysticks is 1, which means that the device connects at least
    int max_joysticks = SDL_NumJoysticks();

    if (max_joysticks < 1) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // this returns, which means that the joystick exists, but it isn't recognized as a game controller.
    if (!SDL_IsGameController(0)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // I never get passed this.
    controller = SDL_GameControllerOpen(0);

    fprintf(stdout, "CONTROLLER: %s\n", SDL_GameControllerName(controller));
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? I've done some preliminary searching as I mentioned, but it seems that usually either the number of joysticks is 0, or everything is recognized.

Also, `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED` isn't firing when I connect the controller.

The controller is connected via USB before I start the program. Also, this is one of the new controllers, and I'm not sure whether the mappings work with that new one. I assume so considering that there are two distinct entries.
Thank you.

EDIT:

I double checked and the PS4 controller works fine as a joystick, but it isn't recognized as a controller, which means that the mapping is incorrect or non-existent. This may be because my controller is "version 2" of the dualshock 4, and I'm not sure whether a 2.0.5-compatible mapping was added. hmmm

Comment: I'm assuming this is related to how SDL2 and most games check for gamepads vs joysticks. I would have to look at the SDL code to be sure. Gamepads tend to require the drivers being detectable by xinput.dll. I'm pretty sure you need special drivers to be installed such as SCPToolkit. Terraria is an example of this. There are xinput wrappers for DS3 controllers you could look into instead of SDL2 API.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works on mac or generally, as SDL is supposed to handle all the driver craziness for you. The controller works fine with other applications. Also, I need to use SDL's system to be consistent with the rest of my input system. I was following this: https://davidgow.net/handmadepenguin/ch6.html

Comment: I have no idea about Mac. Looking at the source... mac isn't even a directory in the joystick folder. I do see iphoneos, though. I can tell you that SDL2 doesn't know the difference between a joystick and a gamepad without it being supported by the developers. IphoneOS only seem to support Steam and "GC" controllers. As can be seen in your link, these are XBox and Steam controllers.

Comment: SDL uses a text file of controller mappings. I don't see why mac would require a special folder. I am surprised that this basic thing is so poorly documented. hmm. I think that you're thinking of how Windows does things.

Comment: @ffhighwind Mac target folder is the Darwin one

Comment: @synchronizer Every OS implements drivers (almost) in their own way so they have to make a version of joystick for each one. This shouldn't affect you tho. You have a newer version available, you could try using #that (2.0.7). Btw are you connecting through USB or bluetooth?

Comment: It's plugged in at start @Aram . (USB). I used homebrew to install SDL and it looks like there is no Mavericks bottle for SDL (they are on 2.0.8). I'd rather not install everything again from source, so I am not sure what to do. I would have liked to try a newer version that uses the newer controller syntax, but as far as I'm aware homebrew can't give me an older version.

Comment: @synchronizer I've used brew too and I have 2.0.7 thats why I was saying that. If you post a better MVCE I might test it tomorrow with my PS4 controller, I have both first gen and second gen controllers (I don't have a mac at home).

Comment: @Aram According to this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/sdl2.rb Mavericks isn't an available bottle, unless I'm misinterpreting it and somehow Mavericks would be able to install from those bottled. --or could it somehow install an older version (2.0.7). I just purchased the controller so it's the second generation. Is it possible that the game controller mapping archive for 2.0.5 doesn't cover those? It would be great if you could check. I don't know how to reduce my example though. All I do is create the window and check whether the joystick is a gamepad.

Comment: Actually, the brew script has "any" above the other bottle cellars, so this may still work. I've seen 2.0.8 used with Mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller was recognized as a joystick but not as a controller, meaning that none of the available mappings I could find (in 2.0.5 controller mapping format) corresponded with the controller. Updating from SDL 2.0.5 to 2.0.8 also updated available mappings it seems, and now the controller is recognized as a game controller.

Note: normally it is a terrible idea to upgrade tools mid-project, but in this case it was safe to do.